# Installing unixODBC and FreeTDS on macOS 10.12

Tags: macos-sierra, freetds, unixodbc

I have a 32 bit application that needs to connect to a *Sybase ASE* database. I know in order to make the database connection I need *unixODBC* and *FreeTDS*. I installed them using the following commands:

> brew install unixodbc 
>   brew install freetds --with-unixodbc

This allowed me to connect to the database and run some query, but it is the 64 bit version on *unixODBC* and my app cannot connect to it.

How can I force the 32 bit installation of *unixODBC* and *FreeTDS* on macOS 10.12?

Thank you